# Traceability Matrix

Tags: manual-testing

I was wondering whether I could get your help with the description/content on this page regarding traceability matrix:

https://www.guru99.com/traceability-matrix.html

I understand the concept that's being explained, but I'm stuck on finishing the rest of the business requirements.

What confuses me is, what would the Test Steps and the Test Data look like for Business Requirements 2 and 3?

Like, in what verbal language would I actually write it down as?

Also, has anyone ever finished the rest of the test cases? If so, could you please share it?

Or is anyone able to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Have a look here for [asking](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You likely get downvotes for it as it somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0):

The views for the above question would be subjective. Depends on person who is preparing the RTM. Make sure the test steps written are easily understandable, However test data depends on the Application Under Test which you would be using. 
For e.g. Test data for B2 would look like BankLogin details of id and password.

Answer (score 0):

Test steps are the series of steps that you need to follow for test case execution and Test data is actually the data which you use in test case execution.
For example : Business Requirement 3 Says that "Customer" can transfer fund from own account to some one else's account. So the steps would be like:

1. Log in to the application.
2. click on transfer
3. Enter the account number.
4. enter the amount to be send.
5. click confirm.
6. Enter transaction password.
   7 Click done.

And test data would be something like:

1. Amount to be transferred for example : 5000
2. Account number of person to whom amount is to be send : XXXXXXXX

Hope it helps.